# How to insert HTML code with awk?

Tags: html, awk

I am trying to insert some HTML code for my Telldus script page. I want create a link-image. I have tried a lot of different alternatives for this code but nothing works.

**AWK CODE to generate off.php**

```
# awk '{print a$1b$1d}' a='<a href="' b='-off.html">' d='<img src='OFF.png'></a><br> ' off1.php > off.php
```

**Result for off.php**

```
# more off.php
<a href="Lampor-off.html">Lampor<img src=OFF.png></a><br>
```

**Result I want for off.php**

```
<a href="Lampor-off.html"><img src=OFF.png></a>Lampor<br>
```

So, I want the image to be a link instead of the word "Lampor".

Comment: Please post sample Input and expected output more clearly as it is not clear.

Comment: What's the purpose of variables like `a='<a href="'` instead of just hard-coding the fixed values in the print statement?

Comment: generating html with awk is weird ... pretty weird

Answer (score 1):

this should do...

```
awk '{print "<a href=\""$1"-off.html\""><img src=OFF.png></a>"$1"<br>"}' file
```